# Which support plan is included with pay-as-you-go accounts on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure

I've signed up for a pay-as-you-go account with Windows Azure, but haven't purchased anything yet.

I have, however, created a support ticket as I could not move storage from an expired trial subscription.

My question is: in the process of creating this ticket, have I implicitly purchased a support plan?

On the ticket form, there is a 'Support Plan: Standard' notice at the bottom. Although I've never tried to purchase this plan, it looks like it costs $300/month on [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/).
[image]

Comment: I've used them and I don't think we were charged, but it's a little tough to tell as I don't get the invoices. I think you're probably fine. The whole pay-for-support thing is relatively new, and I don't think they've actually implemented it fully yet.

Comment: I've just spoken to Microsoft's online support and they've confirmed from the ticket ID that this is a "free case". So it looks ok.

Comment: Microsoft is VERY good about refunding your money for Azure.  I have had 3 separate instances where developers deployed something got charged a bunch and Microsoft will gladly refund the overcharges to keep them engaged on their platform rather AWS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft have only just created the support plans that you see on that page, previously all support was free.  To allow people to try before they buy they're giving away the standard plan till December 31 2012, which is why you're seeing that plan shown.  After this date, unless you pay, you won't be able to raise a support ticket, you'll just have the official MS forums.  And SO of course.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/12/announcing-comprehensive-updates-to-windows-azure-customer-support-offerings-and-free-standard-support-till-dec-31-2012.aspx